# Spanner Table/column locks causing lot of slowness in Dataflow stream Job

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-spanner

There were Exclusive locks on few columns with lock wait time around 2sec, while we try to read (readonly transaction) in dataflow. But dataflow was not able to recover from and step was running without output for 20mins, logs were showing its stuck/waiting on resultset.next().

We are using Apache beam BatchReadOnlyTransaction.executeQuery(Statement) for reading data.

Expected step should progress after locks were released or wait time (2sec) over. Instead, it took almost 20mins to compete the request.

Code:

```
try (ResultSet rs = readOnlyTransaction.executeQuery(statement)) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            Struct struct = rs.getCurrentRowAsStruct();
        }
    }
```

Seen below exception in Logs:

Exception:

> operation ongoing in step ** for at least 30m00s without outputting or completing in state process
> at java.base@11.0.9/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
> at java.base@11.0.9/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
> at java.base@11.0.9/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
> at java.base@11.0.9/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:433)
> at app//com.google.cloud.spanner.AbstractResultSet$GrpcStreamIterator.computeNext(AbstractResultSet.java:939)
> at app//com.google.cloud.spanner.AbstractResultSet$GrpcStreamIterator.computeNext(AbstractResultSet.java:884)
> at app//com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:146)
> at app//com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:141)
> at app//com.google.cloud.spanner.AbstractResultSet$ResumableStreamIterator.computeNext(AbstractResultSet.java:1135)
> at app//com.google.cloud.spanner.AbstractResultSet$ResumableStreamIterator.computeNext(AbstractResultSet.java:1007)
> at app//com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:146)
> at app//com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:141)
> at app//com.google.cloud.spanner.AbstractResultSet$GrpcValueIterator.ensureReady(AbstractResultSet.java:270)
> at app//com.google.cloud.spanner.AbstractResultSet$GrpcValueIterator.getMetadata(AbstractResultSet.java:246)
> at app//com.google.cloud.spanner.AbstractResultSet$GrpcResultSet.next(AbstractResultSet.java:120)

Comment: Can you share the code snippet in Dataflow job and full stacktrace?

Comment: can you share the details?

Comment: updated with full stack trace and code snippet, do you need more details on `BatchReadOnlyTransaction`?